# Cast pointer to larger int

Tags: c

I have a pointer. On a 32-bit system it's 32 bits. On a 64-bit system it's 64 bits.

I have a long long integer field used as an identifier, and sometimes I want to use the pointer value in there. (I never cast back to a pointer - once I've cast it to the integer field, I only ever compare it for equality).

On both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, it seems safe to do this. (On larger pointered systems not so). Is that true?

And then, is there a way to make [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) not give the following warning only when building on platforms where this is safe (which is, at the moment, all target platforms)?

> error: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Werror=int-to-pointer-cast]

Answer (score 10):

According to the standard, there is no guarantee that a pointer fits in an integer type. In practical, otherwise, on mostly personnal computers, there exists several [memory models](http://www.viva64.com/media/images/content/t/Data_model/image2.png). You can see pointer and integer types have not always the same size (even on "conventional" computers).

You should rather use the optional types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`, from C99.

> **C11 (n1570), § 7.20.1.4**
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `intptr_t`.
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `uintptr_t`.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int n = 42;
int *p = &n;
intptr_t i = (intptr_t)(void *)p;
int *q = (void *)i; 

printf("%d\n", *q);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an integer type that is guaranteed to be big enough to hold a pointer, consider `intptr_t` (signed) or `uintptr_t`. The standard guarantees that these datatypes are big enough to hold a pointer. Nothing else might be assumed, especially not that `long int` is long enough.