# How come I can't convert unsigned int pointer to unsigned int?

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to typecast the address of an unsigned int into an unsigned int but when I compile, I get warning:

> cast from pointer to integer of different size

Here is some code to help demonstrate:

```
unsigned int i, ret, offset = 270;
ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset;
```

I would expect that the address of `i` is converted into the unsigned int type but I can't understand why it's not working.

Comment: Try comparing `sizeof(unsigned int)` to `sizeof(unsigned int*)`.

Comment: Your code might be compiled as 64 bit, thus the pointer size grew to 64 bit, but the integer size stayed at 32 bits.

Comment: [cast pointer to larger int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288061/cast-pointer-to-larger-int?rq=1). TLDR: It's not right in general to cast pointers to integer types as the latter is not guaranteed to fit a pointer. Use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` instead.

Comment: @molbdnilo ahh, the sizes are 4 and 8

Comment: "I can't understand why it is not working" - Read the warning message. It tells you exactly why it isn't working.

Comment: @Leandros it did compile as 64 bit. does the pointer grow bigger because each address uses 8 bytes instead of 4 because it's 64 bit

Comment: What is "working"? Based on information hete, you get only warnings and it should work in some implementation-defined manner.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6

Comment: indeed you can, this is just a warning, since size of int is different from system to other

Comment: @milevyo beware saying "just a warning" ... this causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M, well, since we can do some arithmetic operations on pointers, and i am talking about (substitution and addition), warnings just stays warnings. the behavior is well defined - if we already are aware about the size of the `int` -.

Comment: @milevyo no it is not well-defined

Comment: @yasgur99 Yes, 64 bit means your addressing space for memory now uses 64 bits (which are 8 bytes), therefore pointer size has to grow.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `i` is not a pointer. If you need to return a pointer, you might want a pointer variable. In your example, the return value is returning *the position of `i` minus 270* which is nothing but useless to me. And I can't think on any example where this might me useful.